# MultiField.getFields equivalent in Lucene 8?

Tags: lucene

I am using Lucene 8.10.1.
I have the following code :

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(index)));
try
{
      Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);
      for (String termfield : fields) {
        Terms terms = fields.terms(termfield);
        TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator(null);
        int count = 0;
        while (termsEnum.next() != null) {
          count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
      }
    }
```

But I am running into this error.

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getFields(org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader)
  location: class org.apache.lucene.index.MultiFields
```

Couldn't find anything in the docs of 8.10.1.
Please help! Thank you!

Comment: `MultiFields.getFields()` has been removed as of Lucene version 8.0 ([LUCENE-8513](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8513)). I guess you will have to use `FieldInfos.getIndexedFields(reader)` or `FieldInfos.getMergedFieldInfos(reader)`, and then for each field `MultiTerms.getTerms(reader, field)`. I leave it as a comment as I can't test right now, let us know if it works.

Comment: I think MultiTerms.getTerms(reader, field) will suffice.

Comment: `MultiTerms.getTerms(reader, field)` worked for me in Lucene 8.11.0.